# iOS [Swift] – How To Use Custom Animator For VC Transition

Tags: ios, swift, segue, transition

Thanks for your help in advance!

So I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwRvLGPIR0Y) and I created my own custom animator.
My `CustomAnimator` class is done, but I simply do not get how to use it.
I created an extension for my `ViewController` as an `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and now my question is, how can I make a button in my `ViewController` use the `CustomAnimator`-transition to switch to my `NewViewController`?

Thanks a lot guys, I love this community ;)

Raphael

EDIT:
Here is the Code you need to know:
Extension of the LoginViewController

```
extension LoginViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        // Creating an instance of the animator
        let animation = TopDownScrollAnimation()

        if fromVC is LoginViewController {
            animation.transitionMode = .Present
        } else {
            animation.transitionMode = .Dismiss
        }

        return animation
    }
}
```

Custom Animation:

```
class TopDownScrollAnimation: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    enum TransitionMode: Int {
        case Present, Dismiss
    }

    var transitionMode: TransitionMode = .Present


    // Transition duration
    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        switch transitionMode {
        case .Present:
            return 0.4
        case.Dismiss:
            return 0.2
        }
    }


    // Transition animation
    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        // Getting containterView + both views for the transition
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

        switch transitionMode {
        case .Present:
            // Adding toView to the containerView
            toView.frame = CGRect(x: containerView!.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: containerView!.bounds.size.width, height: containerView!.bounds.size.height)
            containerView?.addSubview(toView)

            // Adding fromView to the containerView
            containerView?.addSubview(fromView)

            containerView?.bringSubviewToFront(toView)

            // Getting the duration
            let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

            // Animation
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
                fromView.frame = CGRectOffset(fromView.frame, -containerView!.bounds.size.width, 0)
                toView.frame = containerView!.frame
            }) { (_) in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true) }


        case .Dismiss:
            // Adding the toView to the containerView
            containerView?.addSubview(toView)
            toView.frame = CGRect(x: -containerView!.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: containerView!.bounds.size.width, height: containerView!.bounds.size.height)

            // Adding the fromView and bringing it to the front
            containerView?.addSubview(fromView)
            containerView?.bringSubviewToFront(fromView)

            // Getting the duration
            let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
                fromView.frame = CGRectOffset(fromView.frame, containerView!.bounds.size.width, 0)
                toView.frame = containerView!.frame
            }) { (_) in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true) }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to have a button from LoginViewController that uses the animation to transition to a SignUpViewController without using a NavigationController in the storyboard.

I have also added the in the `viewDidLoad()` of `LoginViewController` the line `navigationController?.delegate = self`.

Comment: Do I presume you're doing a push transition in navigation controller? If you've explicitly set the `delegate` for your navigation controller, its `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:` will be called. And then, when you push to the next scene (either programmatically or via segue), you should see your animation called automatically. I'd suggest adding breakpoint in `animationControllerForOperation` and make sure that's getting called. If not, maybe the navigation controller's `delegate` wasn't set like you thought it was.

Comment: If that's not it, I'd suggest you create [a MCVE, the simplest possible reproducible example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to help you without reproducible example of the problem And we don't want to get lost in tons of unrelated code, which is why we need MCVE.

Comment: Did what you suggested with the breakpoint, it was called and now everything is working. I restarted...Only God knows why :D thx